# What is the exact position of the M2 fastener screw's base on the PCB from the slot for 2280 SSD?

Tags: pcb-design, pcie, ssd

I am designing a PCB that uses NVMe m.2 2280 M-Key SSD. I would like to know what is the exact position of the SSD's screw will be located with respect to the SSD slot. The slot that I am using is https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-2199230-5.html.

I have the measurement details of the slot and the SSD is 80 mm in length, but once it is inserted, I am not sure of the position where the screw provision should come.

Comment: Probably easiest to buy the connector and a 2280 SSD and measure them.

Answer (score 1):

Download datasheets of those SSDs, they have mechanical drawings.

Based on few datasheets, the center of the hole is 1.00 +/- 0.10 mm away from PCB edge, and the PCB is 80.00 +/- 0.15 mm in length.

So extrapolating that, it's 79mm from PCB edge that goes into the connector. Just calculate the position from that based on whatever reference the connector has to the PCB  - it seems to use 1.75 mm from PCB edge to reference.

Answer (score 0):

After insertion and fixing the screw, the card presses against the back side of the slot in the socket. According to the drawing, the slot ends 1.75 mm behind the mounting posts. From there you can work backwards using the known total length of the card.